# Showing/Hiding a control from within another control

Tags: c#, winforms

I have got a Windows forms application with a main application form and two controls I added to my main form.
The first control has got a login button. When that button is pressed, I want to hide control1 and show control2, which is currently hidden.
Hiding control1 works by using this.Hide() in the onClick event of the login button, but I have so far been unable to find a way to reference control2 and call .Show()

[image: control1 in the main form]

How can I show control2 from within the onClick event of the login button?

EDIT:
Hope the below information helps.

Controls:
LoginMenu.cs - Has all of the control's code in it. - Control name in MainForm.cs is loginMenu1
TicketSearch.cs - Has all of the control's code in it. - control name in MainForm.cs is ticketSearch1

After adding all controls, I rebuilt the project and dragged them into the main form from the tools menu.

The code for the login button is in LoginMenu.cs

```
    public partial class LoginMenu : UserControl
{
    public LoginMenu()
    {
        //
        // The InitializeComponent() call is required for Windows Forms designer support.
        //
        InitializeComponent();

        *CODE HERE*


    }

    void ButtonLoginClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        *CODE HERE*

        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = 
            (HttpWebResponse)loginTest.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {


            if (ex.Message.Contains("401") == true)
            {
                *CODE HERE*
            }
            else if (ex.Message.Contains("403") == true)
            {

                *CODE HERE*

                //Hide login control. This works
                this.Hide();

                //This is where I want to show the control ticketSearch1

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post what code you currently have?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55129687/3110834

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to those who tried to help. I learnt something new today.

For some reason, I don't quite understand I could not access the controls in MainForm.cs from LoginMenu.cs even though they are in the same namespace and the control 'Modifiers' property is set to 'Public'.

I resolved this by adding the following method call to my login button onClick action to reference the control I wanted `Form.ActiveForm.Controls.Find("ticketSearch1", true)[0].Show();`

Answer (score 0):

But it should work.
Look at the properties of Control2 and pick the name (or set a name) under the line "(Name)".

then you should:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    firstcontrol.Hide();
    secondcontrol.Show();
}
```

it should work.
Maybe you failed with the placing of the control. So look what happens if you start your programm with the first control hidden and the second one shown. And try to hide the second control and show the first.
There must be the problem.

Did you place your Control via "Toolbox"?
Or do you call your Control via code?

EDIT:
Referring to your inserted Code, it seems, that you call this code in your Usercontrol.

So you need to set the second Usercontrol to "Public". When you click on it and go to the Properties, you choose "Mofifiers" and set it to public.

Now you should look for the (Name) Attribute in his properties.

Then just add:

```
NameOfYourSecondControl.Show();
```

This will fix your problem.

Comment: Maybe you try to access the Control from another file and then you need to set the control public.

Comment: I added the controls via the toolbox. I added some code to my question. Thank you.

Comment: @MondQ i editted my answer. It will help, if not, tell me.

Comment: Thanks Loa, maybe you are onto something. I am actually not using VS, but SharpDevelop, but I went into the properties of the ticketSearch control in my main form and set 'Modifier' to 'Public', but that didn't help.
Whenever I start typing ticketSearch intelliSense only suggests using the ticketSearch class itself. Just typing ticketSearch1.Show() doesn't work either.
I wonder if it's an IDE issue. Is there a way to set the modifier programatically?
PS: Using VS code is not an option due to licensing in a workplace environment. I doubt my employer would pay for a license since I am not dev

Comment: Actually just tested it in Visual Studio with my community license and the issue is the same.

Comment: Then try to handle it through your Main Form, where your controls are embedded. Does it work if you just place a button and add control.Show() in the click eventhandler in your main form?