# How to update the label text in the form with usercontrol?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I put a button inside UserControl and put this UserControl in the form.
I want the textbox text in the form to be updated when the button is clicked.

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 form1 = new Form1();
            form1.textBox1.Text = "1";

            //The textbox text is not updated!
        }
    }
```

The textbox text is not updated

Comment: You are creating a new Form1. You are not showing it. You probably meant to update an existing Form1.

Comment: Yes, I want to update the form - I don't want the new form to open.
what should I do ?

Comment: @mehrannosrati I update the answer. Please take a look.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55053527/3110834

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36128148/3110834

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create a new Form. Please remove that line.

I guess you are trying to set text for a TextBox in Form and your button is in Usercontrol which is child component of the Form.

If so please register an EventHandler from your Form and fire event from your Button in UserControl.

Register an EventHandler in your UserControl:

```
public event EventHandler ButtonClicked;
protected virtual void OnButtonClicked(EventArgs e)
{
    var handler = ButtonClicked;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, e);
}
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    OnButtonClicked(e);
}
```

In your Form, you subscribe the event from UserControl:

```
this.userControl1.ButtonClicked += userControl11_ButtonClicked;

private void userControl11_ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.TextBox1.Text = "1";
}
```

Let me know your result.

Comment: In button_click `this` refers to an instance of `UserControl1`. That does not have a TextBox1 member.

Comment: Ah so the TextBox is in UserControl, not in the Form

Comment: No, the textbox is in the form and the button is in UserControl

Comment: please refer to the reference to raise event in child component and subscribe in parent one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36130796/4489400

Comment: You're welcome. If you find this helpful, can you please upvote and mark this answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new `Form1`. You are not showing it. You probably meant to update an existing `Form1`. I suppose the `UserControl1` is placed on the `Form1`. Then you can do this:

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the parent form
    Form1 myForm = (Form1) this.parent;
    myForm.TextBox1.Text = "1";
}
```

If your `UserControl1` is not on `Form1`, then you need to pass a reference somehow.

Comment: error = 'UserControl1' does not contain a definition for and no accessible extension method accepting a first argument of type 'UserControl1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: That has nothing to do with the line I added. There must be something else wrong.

Comment: 'UserControl1' does not contain a definition for parent and no accessible extension method parent accepting a first argument of type 'UserControl1' could be found

Answer (score 0):

remove  the row where you create a new Form

```
 public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
        {
            public UserControl1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                textBox1.Text = "1";

                //The textbox text is not updated!
            }
        }
```

Comment: The name 'TextBox1' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @mehrannosrati sorry for the late answer.
If you haven't fixed yet, please create a github project with this problem and I will try to help you.